# nginx: root chosen based on path

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, root, directive

I want the following.
http://some.site/person1/some/path should access `/home/person1/some/path` (and http://some.site/person1 accesses `/home/person1/index.html`) and http://some.site/person2/some/path should access `/home/person2/some/path` (and http://some.site/person2 accesses `/home/person2/index.html`). There will be many `personX`es. It's important to use a regular expression to tell nginx where to find everything.

I tried coming up with a set of location, root and rewrite directives that would work. The closest I came was this for my `sites-available/website`.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        root /some/default/root;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /person1 {
                root /home/person1;
                rewrite ^/person1(.*)$ $1 break;
        }
}
```

This does what I want with all paths except for ones of the form http://some.site/person1. In this case, nginx doesn't access `/home/person1/index.html` like I want. Instead, the regex returns an empty string which nginx doesn't like (I see complaints in the nginx/error.log).

Answer (score 0):

when you have common start root dir in /home, you can try with:

```
location ~* /person\d+ {
    root /home;
}
```